# Using variables in Nginx request_uri

Tags: variables, nginx, lua, webserver, openresty

Good morning programmers,
I'm trying to protect a file, and for that I just want to allow the request_uri that I define.
Example:

```
if ($request_uri !~* "d=123") {
return 403;
}
```

In this case, that example works, but I would like to do something like this:

```
set $teste 123;
if ($request_uri !~* "d=$teste") {
return 403;
}
```

So I want to make it via variables, is that possible? Cause I already tested a bunch of examples and none of them worked.

**P.S: I'm using OpenResty (Nginx+Lua) so if there is a possible solution with lua I would accept it too.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `d` is your query argument and `123` is it's value, you could try something like this:

```
set $teste 123;
if ($request_uri ~* "[?&]d=([^&]*)") { set $d $1; }
if ($d != $teste) {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: Well, its working pretty well, thank you for the help, I'm new on stackoverflow there is some way I can give you a "+1"?

Comment: Unless you have 50 reputation you can't, but you can accept the answer )

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is it possible to also do the variable "$teste" random instead of static?

Comment: I'm answered your second question. And why are you don't accept an answer if it works?